# User connected can't access to the page even if he has the expected roles to access to it

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

All user connected with the good roles and authorities and they can't access to the page with errors **403** **access** **denied** for this user :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Professor getConnectedProf() {
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String username;
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            username = principal.toString();
        }
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
        for (SimpleGrantedAuthority simpleGrantedAuthority : authorities) {
            logger.info("the authorité for the current user is = " + simpleGrantedAuthority.getAuthority());
        }

        logger.info("this the username of the connected user : " + username);
        return sp.getProfByMatricule(username);
    }
```

this return those value :

```
18:12:50.097 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] INFO  c.o.m.AppInitializer#148 the authorité for the current user is = ADMIN
18:12:50.098 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] INFO  c.o.m.AppInitializer#148 the authorité for the current user is = DEPCHEF
18:12:50.098 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] INFO  c.o.m.AppInitializer#148 the authorité for the current user is = PROF
18:12:50.098 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] INFO  c.o.m.AppInitializer#148 the authorité for the current user is = USER
18:12:50.099 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] INFO  c.o.m.AppInitializer#151 this the username of the connected user : admin
```

And my security.xml is like this :

```
<http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('PROF')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasAnyRole('PROF','ADMIN','DEPCHEF','CHEF')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/mission" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN','USER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/mission/*" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN','USER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/addMission/*" access="hasRole('PROF')"/>
        
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index" authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>
        
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </http>
```

and when I try to get /index I get the 403 access denied.

```
HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden
Type Status Report

Message Access is denied

Description The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hasRole()` doesn't seem to work when moving from Spring 3 to Spring 4. Using `hasAuthority()` worked for me,

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-role-prefixing), `Spring Security 4` automatically prefixes any role with `ROLE_`. So, if you specify this:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasAnyRole('PROF','ADMIN','DEPCHEF','CHEF')"/>
```

it is implying this:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_PROF','ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_DEPCHEF','ROLE_CHEF')"/>
```

And since you do not have the `ROLE_` prefix as per your logs, this explains the 403.

As per Rob Winch s' explanation [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2984):

> The reason is because there is more to authorities than just roles.
> For example, you can have a group based authority. The ROLE_ is a way
> to distinguish between the type of the authority.
>
> If the expression is stated as hasRole, then this convention should
> automatically be applied since the user is explicitly stating it is a
> role based authority. So the problem is that you are not using the
> ROLE_ prefix. You can follow the migration guide to figure out how to
> resolve your problem
> http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#m3to4
> One alternative is to use hasAuthority instead of hasRole. The
> hasAuthority expression works because it does not imply ROLE_ being
> appended to the value passed in.